# Can I go on a B1 visa to the US for a training while my L1 petition is being filed?

Tags: usa, business, l1-visa

My L1 petition is being filed. Is it OK if I travel on a B1 visa to the US for the purpose of training?

Answer (score -1):

Attorney usually recommend not to travel on B1 while L1 petition is in progress.

Comment: This may well be good advice (I don't know), but the lack of circumstances, info about attorney experience and location, and citable law or other info make this filed-three-years later-by-the-OP answer less than useful.